# If you star then pin then unstar the message will not show up in the starboard

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars, chat-pins

I found a bug, it is if you star a message then pin and then unstar the message it will look pinned by the little pin icon by the message but will not be pinned in the starboard. [You can see the bug here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55393/special-room-for-testing-bugs)
[image: Step one]

[image: Final result]

Comment: -1, needs more animated gifs and hand-drawn circles :-P

Comment: Also when you pin your message, then remove the pin, you've starred your own message and can't unstar it because 'you can't star your own message'.

Comment: Wait what... That is great